# How to multiple setStater with just one rendering with useStateHook

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I use setState like following code which make multiple rendering so I looking for multiple setState with just one rendering.

Please give me advice.

```
  function name(parameter) {
    axios
      .get("/api/url
      .then(response => {
        // console.log(response);
        setEventList(response.data.data);
        setItemsCountPerPage(response.data.per_page);
        setTotalItemsCount(response.data.total);
        setActivePage(response.data.current_page);
        setCountFrom(response.data.from);
        setCountTo(response.data.to);
      })
  }
```

Comment: You probably want to initialize a single state holding the response `data` object.